# Why does my formula suggest mixing it in only a portion of the water?

Tags: formula, milk, water

The directions for [Holle baby formula](https://organicstart.com/holle-1-milk-formula/) say to boil water, let it cool, put 2/3 of the water into the bottle, then add the formula, then add the remaining 1/3 of the water.

Is it necessary to add 2/3 of the water, then the formula, then the remaining 1/3 of the water? Or can we just add the full water amount and then the formula?

Comment: https://organicstart.com/preparation-feeding-holle-1/ says your wife is right. Having some awareness of chemistry I'm pretty sure it will not explode if you do it wrong, and I suspect it will still provide some nutrition though.

Comment: If your tap water is safe to drink, you don't have to boil it either.  It's a million times easier if your baby is used to drinking formula made with room temp water from the tap.  As long as the bottle has enough room to shake the formula properly, you don't have to add the water in stages.

Answer (score 3):

That's only helpful if your bottle is too full with the full amount of water, making it hard to dissolve the formula by shaking. If that's not the case (i.e., there's enough air above the water+formula), there's no need to fill the bottle in stages.

Reading the company's [instructions](https://organicstart.com/preparation-feeding-holle-1/) (pointed out by [not store bought dirt](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/users/26011/not-store-bought-dirt)) we can also see that they advice against using microwaved water, which is not fact based - so I'd take whatever they say with a grain of salt. Also, as [swbarnes2](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/users/9368/swbarnes2) mentioned in the comments, if your kid is old enough you would do a great favor to yourself by using water at room temperature and, if safe, from the tap.

Comment: At what age does it become safe to use water at room temperature?

Comment: "they advice against using microwaved water, which is not fact based" I'll point out that it could be, if it was intended to prevent people from using non-microwave safe containers from heating their water, and then poisoning their kids with chemicals leeched from the plastics in the container, or to prevent injuries from supercritical boiled water explosions. They've got to aim these warnings at the lowest common denominator, after all.

Comment: @Plumenator Even newborns can be fine with room-temperature formula - especially as they get older, they might _prefer_ to have warmer milk, but even in hospital maternity wards bottles are often offered at room temperature, so you don't have to worry about safety.

Comment: @nick012000 Both possible issues you mention have to do with overheating the water - that'll be a problem regardless of how it's heated, microwaved or stove or boiler. And no regulation conforming bottle will "leech chemicals" when in contact with hot water: and if they will, then the formula directions are even worse, since they instruct the parent to pour boiling water into the bottle.

Comment: @stafusa "no regulation conforming bottle will "leech chemicals" when in contact with hot water" It might, if it's not labelled as being microwave safe. This is why you never use plastic containers in the microwave unless they've got the microwave safe label on them.

Comment: @nick012000 Can you give me an example of a plastic bottle that releases chemicals when in the microwave but not when boiling water is poured in it?

Comment: @stafusa https://digg.com/2017/microwaving-plastic

Comment: @nick012000 Your link mentions nothing about microwave specific problems, only heating problems. And ends with "If you're still a little apprehensive, trust the words of David Roylance, a plastics engineering professor at MIT. "Personally, I just microwave items willy-nilly and if they get hot that's good enough for me," he wrote to me in an email. "Others are more cautious, worrying the item might exude something dangerous – not likely, in my view.""